# How to populate result Sqldatareader multiple row to textbox

Tags: c#, vb.net, ado.net, sqldatareader

How to populate result from looping array sqldatareader to a varriable or textbox?
I have a table and some row based a code for multiple rows, like here:

[image: enter link description here]

and how to populate to textbox like here :

[image: enter link description here]

```
Dim cmd2 As New SqlCommand("Select * from SI where id_group='211'")
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
         While dr.Read()

        'what is the right code for this case

    End While
```

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this. Assuming that the textboxes are named sequentially as txtName1, txtName2, txtBook1, txtBook2 etc. and the field names are "name", "book" etc.

```
        int count = 0;
        Dictionary<string, string> TextBoxValues = new Dictionary<string,string>();
        while(dr.Read())
        {
            count++;
            TextBoxValues.Add("txtName" + count, dr["name"].ToString());
            TextBoxValues.Add("txtBook" + count, dr["book"].ToString());
        }

        txtName1.Text = TextBoxValues[txtName1.ID];
        txtName2.Text = TextBoxValues[txtName2.ID];

        txtBook1.Text = TextBoxValues[txtBook1.ID];
        txtBook2.Text = TextBoxValues[txtBook2.ID];
```